# Pixate: How to change the background color of the selected tab?

Tags: pixate

What CSS should I use to change the background color of the selected UITabBarItem using pixate?

I've tried this, and it doesn't seem to work.

tab-bar-item:selected {

background-color: gray;

}

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some reason I had to use "tab-bar selection"

I also had to set the background size of it to something reasonable so that it would work.  I don't know if this is the way but it works for me.

```
tab-bar {
    background-color: red;
    selected-color: white;
}
  tab-bar-item {
    color: green;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 12px;
  }

  tab-bar-item:selected {
    color: purple;
  }

tab-bar selection {
  background-size:64px 48px;
  background-color: linear-gradient(red,yellow);
  box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}
```